# How to fix void value not ignored in a function that returns string?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm getting this error and I don't know why...
I surfed on google but not got asolution can anyone pls help
I have no clue why is this happening.
I thought that the string return type was messing up but char* return type also didn't help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int isoperand(char x){
    if(x=='+' || x=='-' ||x=='*' ||x=='/')
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int precedence(char x){
    if(x=='+' || x=='-')
        return 1;
    else if(x=='*' ||x=='/')
        return 2;
    return 0;
}

string convert(string infix){
    stack<char> s;
    string postfix;
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(infix[i]!='\0'){
        if(isoperand(infix[i]))
            postfix[j++]=infix[i++];
        else{
            if(precedence(infix[i])>precedence(s.top()))
                s.push(infix[i++]);
            else
                postfix[j++]=s.pop(); //Error here.
        }
    }
    while(!s.empty()){
        postfix[j++]=s.pop();
    }
    return postfix;
}

int main(){
    string infix="a+b*c";
    string postfix;
    postfix==convert(infix);
    cout<<postfix;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the error message in question! (I suggest pasting it as a second "code" block, other people would use `> ` to demarcate a quotation.) You should also describe what you're trying to do in the code block in question, and what you expected it to do instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of [`std::stack::pop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) is `void`. Hence, you may not use:

```
postfix[j++]=s.pop();
```

You need to use:

```
postfix[j++] = s.top();
s.pop();
```

Since that line is in an `else` block, you'll have to use:

```
else
{
   postfix[j++] = s.top();
   s.pop();
}
```

Make the same change in the two places in your code that has the same error.

---

Other errors in your code:

1. You are accessing `postfix` using out of bounds indices. Instead of using `postfix[j++] = ...`, you can use `postfix.push_back(...)`.
2. You are calling `s.top()` without checking whether `s` is empty. When `s` is empty, the call `s.top()` throws an exception in my environment.

Here's a fixed up version that works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int isoperand(char x){
   if(x=='+' || x=='-' ||x=='*' ||x=='/')
      return 0;
   else
      return 1;
}

int precedence(char x){
   if(x=='+' || x=='-')
      return 1;
   else if(x=='*' ||x=='/')
      return 2;
   return 0;
}

string convert(string infix){
   stack<char> s;
   string postfix;
   int i=0;
   while(infix[i]!='\0')
   {
      if(isoperand(infix[i]))
      {
         postfix.push_back(infix[i++]);
      }
      else
      {
         if ( s.empty() )
         {
            s.push(infix[i++]);
         }
         else
         {
            if ( precedence(infix[i])>precedence(s.top()) ) 
            {
               s.push(infix[i++]);
            }
            else
            {
               postfix.push_back(s.top());
               s.pop();
            }
         }
      }
   }
   while(!s.empty()){
      postfix.push_back(s.top());
      s.pop();
   }
   return postfix;
}

int main(){
   string infix="a+b*c";
   string postfix;
   postfix=convert(infix);
   cout<<postfix;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AnshShrivastava, you accepted my answer. Does it mean that your code works ok now?

Comment: Yes the error is gone, but, still there is some or the other problem that causes the code to not run, can you please run it on a compiler and check. I am out of luck..

Answer (score 1):

The is the error message:

```
main.cpp:40:36: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
                 postfix[j++]=s.pop(); //Error here.
                                    ^
```

Error message indicates the return-value of a function is 'void', but you are trying to assign it to a non-void variable.

In your case, `std::stack<T,Container>::pop()` return type is void.